# segfault on readdir call

Tags: c, valgrind, coredump, readdir

I'm trying to perform a readdir(): here is the code:

```
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *dirp;

if (dp = opendir("saves") == NULL) {
    my_printf("Cannot open saves directory.\n");
    return 84;
} else if ((dirp = readdir(dp)) == NULL) {
    printf("hello\n");
} else 
    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);
```

I've got a segfault on the `while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)` and the program do not cross the else if statement.

Valgrind output :

```
==4398== Invalid read of size 4
==4398==    at 0x4AB99C3: readdir (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
==4398==    by 0x10C047: save_map (save_button.c:23)
==4398==    by 0x10C0ED: save_button_event (save_button.c:36)
==4398==    by 0x10BBA7: check_close (window_process.c:52)
==4398==    by 0x10A44F: main (my_world.c:19)
==4398==  Address 0x4 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (dp = opendir("saves") == NULL)
```

You missed the parens around the assignment here which you need because `==` has higher precedence than `=`.

You've assigned the result of the comparison to `dp` which is certainly not a valid pointer.

You need:

```
if ((dp = opendir("saves")) == NULL)
```